# Can't input date variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a directory /user/reports under which many files are there, one of them is :

```
report.active_user.30092018.77325.csv
```

I need output as number after date i.e. **77325** from above file name.

I created below command to find a value from file name:

```
ls /user/reports | awk -F. '/report.active_user.30092018/ {print $(NF-1)}'
```

Now, I want current date to be passed in above command as variable and get result:

```
ls /user/reports | awk -F. '/report.active_user.$(date +'%d%m%Y')/ {print $(NF-1)}'
```

But not getting required output.

Tried bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_date=`date +%d%m%Y`

 active=$(ls /user/reports | awk -F. '/report.active_user.${_date}/ {print $(NF-1)}')


 echo $active
```

But still output is blank.

Please help with proper syntax.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

You don't need awk for this: you can manage with the shell's capabilities

```
for file in report.active_user."$(date "+%d%m%Y")"*; do
    tmp=${file%.*}      # remove the extension
    number=${tmp##*.}   # remove the prefix up to and including the last dot
    echo "$number"
done
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

As @cyrus said you must use double quotes in your variable assignment because simple quote are use only for string and not for containing variables.

**Bas use case**

```
number=10
string='I m sentence with or wihtout var $number'
echo $string
```

**Correct use case**

```
number=10
string_with_number="I m sentence with var $number"
echo $string_with_number
```

You can use simple quote but not englobe all the string

```
number=10
string_with_number='I m sentence with var '$number
echo $string_with_number
```

Comment: If you're taking the variable out of single quotes, put the variable in double quotes: `string_with_number='I m sentence with var '"$number"`